# How to NOT show glyphicon-ok if field is left empty?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-ajaxq

[image]I have a "txtPhone" input filter that is NOT mandatory, but can accept only Phone Numbers, so:

```
 <label class="control-label">Phone</label>
<input type="text" id="txtPhone" class="form-control intonly" maxlength="12" placeholder="Phone" name="Phone">
```

Bootstrap Validation

```
Phone: {
                        validators: {
                            regexp: {
                                regexp: /^((091|\+91)?|\((091|\+91)?\)|(91)?|\(91\)|0)? ?[7-9][0-9]{9}$/,
                                message: 'The Indian Phone No must contain 10 digits'
                            },

                        }
                    },
```

But when i clicking submit button tick shown in textbox.

Comment: but its not mandatory.

Comment: So what's the problem? If the field is empty it's valid...

Comment: No Need to glyphicon-ok if field is left empty. this is my requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After Long struggling JesusGrace i find the answer

```
  Bootstrap Validation

     Phone: {
                     enabled: false,
                    validators: {
                        regexp: {
                            regexp: /^((091|\+91)?|\((091|\+91)?\)|(91)?|\(91\)|0)? ?[7-9][0-9]{9}$/,
                            message: 'The Indian Phone No must contain 10 digits'
                        },

                    }
                },


        .on('keyup', '[name="Phone"]', function () {
                var isEmpty = $(this).val() == '';
                $('#form1')
                       .formValidation('enableFieldValidators', 'Phone', !isEmpty);
                // Revalidate the field when user start typing in the Phone field
                if ($(this).val().length == 1) {
                    $('#form1').formValidation('validateField', 'Phone')
                }
            })
```